# Profiling ASP.NET site with Red-Gate Ants Profiler 6.3

Tags: asp.net, iis, ants

I have an asp.net site that i'm trying to profile with Ants Profiler 6.3 but I am having some issues. I can't profile from IIS using either original port or a custom port. IE will open and then show a page saying Internet Explorer cannot show the page and then the profiler will say profiling is complete. I can go to the url just fine.

When I attach to the wp3.exe process I get some results, but nothing related to my code. I have to run the site from IIS, I can't profile individual pages because physical pages don't exist.

How do I profile a site then? How do I tell Ants where the source code is? IIS is pointing directly at the site's root folder.

- Ants Profiler 6.3
- IIS 7.5
- .NET 4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run Ants in Admin mode and you should be all good.

Comment: That's just about idiotic. (ants, not your answer). It works when I run in admin mode. Why wouldn't ants warn me about it or ask me to start in admin mode?